# How to change SPA page number onclick? JavaScript button

Tags: javascript

I have next button how can I change the page number when I click on the button?

```
function pagination_build(){
        const pagination_buttons = document.createElement('div');
        const next_button = document.createElement('button');
        next_button.innerHTML += 'Next'
        pagination_buttons.appendChild(next_button);
        pagination_buttons.classList.add('pagination_buttons');
        document.querySelector('#show-posts').appendChild(pagination_buttons);
        next_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            
            load_posts();
        });
}

function load_posts(){
  document.querySelector('#page-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#load-profile').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#posts-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#show-posts').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#post-form').onsubmit = function() {
        compose_post();
    }
    fetch('/posts/all_posts') // url with that API
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(all_posts => {
        // Loop and show all the posts.
        console.log(all_posts.post_count)
        if(all_posts.post_count > 3){
            pagination_build();
        }
        all_posts.posts.forEach(function(post) { // loop to loop over each object
            build_post(post)
        });
    });
document.querySelector('#show-posts').innerHTML = ""
}
```

views.py

```
def show_posts(request):
    all_posts = NewPost.objects.all()
    all_posts = all_posts.order_by("-date_added").all()
    all_posts_count = all_posts.count()
    paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 3)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return JsonResponse({
        "post_count": all_posts.count(),
        "posts": [website_post.serialize() for website_post in page_obj]
     }, safe=False)
```

My backend handles which posts to load depends on the current page number by (request.get) but my button is in JavaScript and I need to change the page number on click

Comment: Please show us your `load_posts` function.

Comment: aren't you always fetching all posts? you need to fetch only the desired post (by id) and update your page content accordingly. Or maybe i didn't understand what do you mean by changing page number?

Comment: Yes, I fetch all posts, but my backend only returns pagination of the posts, so I need to add a button "next" that changes the current page number and then I need to fetch again, and my backend method supposed to return the  next posts by detecting the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let currentPage = 0;
function pagination_build(){
        /*...*/
        next_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
            currentPage++;
            load_posts();
        });
}
function load_posts(){
    /* ... */
    fetch(currentPage ? `/posts/${ currentPage }` : '/posts/all_posts') // url with that API
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((all_posts) => {
       window.history.pushState(null, null, `/post/${ currentPage }`);
       console.log(all_posts.post_count);
       /* ... */
    }
}
```

Comment: how is this a valid answer to the question? please explain your solution

Comment: If I understood correctly, the problem is nested in the url change of a SPA. Again, If I undersatnd correctly, the problem is to change the URL without reloading the page, as `window.location.href = newURL` would do. The sole purpose being to load the same page when refreshed but not reloading on the page (to keep the current state of the app).

Comment: Either that, or I got it completly wrong and I would delete this if it's the case

Comment: It's true I need to change the URL without refreshing the page, I kind of understood your solution but I need to add URLs first for it to work because currently, my URLs that I see on the frontend are simply localhost/# is that true? -  also can you please explain how the part (/[0-9]+$, pageNumber); works?

Comment: I think I see the problem, and my answer get it right for one part. `load_posts()` should be `load_posts(page = 0)` and `fetch('/posts/all_posts')` should become `fetch(page || '/posts/all_posts')` (0 bieng interpreted as null).
The regExp on the other hand doesn't do much here, loadPosts should set the page with `window.history` by setting it with the `page` variable passed on `loadPosts`

Comment: I edited the answer, should give you better hints on how to build this up

Comment: Thanks! I did get the idea and I got to a solution that seems to work, I have posted my answer, open to any suggestions.

Comment: 1 problem I found tho if I keep clicking next after getting to the last page, it continues to increment the currentpage because of ++, I need to find a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

After getting help, I have managed to make the "Next" Button to act and show the posts on the next page.
not sure if it's the best solution tho, open for any recommendations.

// the pagination function which builds the next button, and every time I click on next it increases the currentpage number which I use on load_posts function.

```
let currentPage = 1;
function pagination_build(){
    const pagination_buttons = document.createElement('div');
    const next_button = document.createElement('button');
    next_button.innerHTML += 'Next'
    pagination_buttons.appendChild(next_button);
    pagination_buttons.classList.add('pagination_buttons');
    document.querySelector('#show-posts').appendChild(pagination_buttons);
    next_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        currentPage++;
        load_posts();
    });
}

function load_posts(){
  document.querySelector('#page-view').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#load-profile').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('#posts-view').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#show-posts').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('#post-form').onsubmit = function() {
        compose_post();
    }
    console.log(currentPage)
    fetch(`/posts/all_posts?page=${currentPage}`) // url with that API
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(all_posts => {
        // Loop and show all the posts.
        if(all_posts.post_count > 3){
            pagination_build();
        }
        all_posts.posts.forEach(function(post) { // loop to loop over each object
            build_post(post)
        });
    });
document.querySelector('#show-posts').innerHTML = ""
}
```

views.py

```
def show_posts(request):
    all_posts = NewPost.objects.all()
    all_posts = all_posts.order_by("-date_added").all()
    all_posts_count = all_posts.count()
    paginator = Paginator(all_posts, 10)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return JsonResponse({
        "post_count": all_posts.count(),
        "posts": [website_post.serialize() for website_post in page_obj]
     }, safe=False)
```